# How to duplicate a variable in a dataset in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a variable with 54 observations. How do I make the variable repeat several times over in a dataset?

ex:

```
Var1   Var2   Var3
 2       4      5
 4       5      7
 6       3      6
```

but I want it to look like

```
Var1   Var2   Var3
 2       4      5
 4       5      7
 6       3      6
 2       4      5
 4       5      7
 6       3      6
 2       4      5
 4       5      7
 6       3      6
```

edit:

I'm trying to do in SAS what is done in R by:
    `x = cbind(1.5, 17, 2.5, 12, 19.3)
    y = rep(x,times=4)
    y`

I have a do loop in SAS but it just repeats each observation instead of repeating the entire vector.

Comment: You're not providing enough information to make sense of your question.  Provide a small example (say, 4 observations 3 variables or somesuch) that's sufficient to completely show your problem.

Comment: Edited. Hopefully it makes a bit more sense.

Comment: So you want the _rows_ duplicated?  (I would note, "vector" is not a SAS term; "row" and "Column" are.  Row is left-right column is up-down.)

Comment: Sorry, I want the columns duplicated. Kind of new to programming and all. ):

Comment: What you showed is rows duplicated, though.  What do you actually want?

Comment: The first set of code in your answer is what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: If you actually want columns duplicated, you can't exactly do that in SAS the way you do it in R (or another matrix language) unless you use SAS/IML (which is a matrix language like R).  SAS (and other database-like languages) tend to assume that observations (rows) are the unit of doing-things-with, while columns are attributes of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the entire dataset duplicated, in order, you would repeat the `set` statement.

```
data want;
do _iter = 1 to 4;
  do _n_ = 1 to nobs_c;
    set sashelp.class nobs=nobs_c point=_n_;
    output;
  end;
end;
stop;
run;
```

Of course, you could also just do

```
data want;
set sashelp.class;
do _n_ = 1 to 4;
  output;
end;
run;
```

and then just sort the dataset by whatever is appropriate.